# Retriving data between two symbols?

Tags: java

Can anyone help to fetch the data between two symbols, for example, i am having the data in the file as

```
 /*
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //Sistema: Abanks
  //Modulo:  Bus de Integracion (Capa de servicio - TDP)
  //Usuario: ALFA / IVSO / RIAP / LEDA
  //Fecha de Elaboración: 01-06-2016 / 01-01-2017
  //Variables:
  //Modificacion: MOD 001 13.01.2017 ALFA/IVSO/RIAP
                  MOD 002 26.05.2017 RIAP Menus Permitidos para el canal HOMEJUR
                  MOD 003 31.05.2017 RIAP
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  */
```

I need the output between /* data */ these two symbols.

Comment: whats wrong with indexOf and substring?

Comment: You need to try yourself and ask any problems if you face once you try, you just can't ask us like _do my work_. Please read Help Center.

Comment: Use a regular expression to replace anything that comes before `/*` or after `*/` with an empty string perhaps?

Comment: so you need something like: ***"Sistema:Abanks"***, ***"Modulo:Bus de integracion"*** etc etc ?????

Comment: fr=new FileReader(file);
   br=new BufferedReader(fr);
   
   String sCurrneline;
   
   br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   
   while((sCurrneline=br.readLine())!=null){
    
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([/*].+?[*/])");

Comment: below is my code

Comment: @JaganMohan I gave you a code sample below which is along the lines of what might work for you.  Your above pasted code won't work, because you're using the wrong pattern to match across line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
String input = "/*\n  /// Content goes here ///\n*/ stuff stuff /* More Content */";
String pattern = "/\\*(.*?)\\*/";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found content:\n " + m.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found content:

  /// Content goes here ///

Found content:
  More Content
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: The problem is the line breaks.  Maybe I can salvage this answer before someone else posts.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I fixed it.  The trick is to use `DOTALL` mode when building the `Pattern`.  Believe it or not, I never had the need to use this in Java before.